If derivative of $f$ has continous extension, $f$ is continously differentiable
Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x_0 \in U$.
Let $f$ be a continous function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which is continously differentiable everywhere on $U$, except for $x_0$.
Show that if $f'|_{U \setminus {x_0}}$ has a continous extension (there exists $g : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g|_{U \setminus {x_0}} = f'|_{U \setminus {x_0}}$), then $f$ is continously differentiable on all of $U$ with $f' = g$.
I've seen a rough proof of this, but I'm not entirely convinced. Here's my attempt:
We need to show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = g(x_0).$$
We already know $g(x_0)$ exists. By the mean value theorem, we have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(\xi) = g(\xi).
$$
Taking the limit on both sides:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0} g(\xi)
$$
and that's supposed to conclude the proof, because $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0} g(\xi) = g(x_0)$.
I can follow the logic, but I'm concerned about the very last statement, i.e. $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0} g(\xi) = g(x_0)$.
Is it valid to say this?

For fixed $x,x_0$ the MVT yields a $\xi\in (x,x_0)$ (or in $(x_0,x)$ if $x_0<x$) with $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$.
For the limit value that concerns you, we now consider an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in $U$ with $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\neq x_0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Applying the MVT we achieve a sequence $(\xi_ n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$:
$$\forall n\in \mathbb N\colon f'(\xi_n)=\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x}$$ and for all $n\in \mathbb N$: $$\xi_n\in (x,x_0)\cup (x_0,x).$$The latter one implies:
$$|\xi_n-x_0|\leq |x-x_n|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,$$i.e. $$\xi_n\to x_0.$$
Since $g$ is continuous on $U$, the following applies according to the sequence criterion
$$g(\xi_n)\to g(x_0).$$Since $(x_n)_n$ was arbitrary, the following applies $$\lim _{\substack{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x \neq x_0}} g(\xi)=g\left(x_0\right).$$
